# Multiprocessing cause DLL load fail and many errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, python-multiprocessing

When `multiprocessing.Pool` creat a large pool, it seems too many memorys are used.

This is a minimum demo, I have 32 CPU cores and 32 G memory:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def f():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(32)
    for i in range(5):
        pool.apply_async(f)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If numpy or anything else is not imported, the code runs correctly. But with any "big" lib imported, this code raise a lot of errors. Ofcourse these "big" libs are not big enough to consume all of my memorys.

I tried `map_async()` but still got the same problem.

Error codes are very long, I extract some errors here and full traceback is too long to be attached.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
DLL load failed while importing bit_generator: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
MemoryError
File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
```

In this demo if I create a smaller pool, for example `Pool(16)`, every thing is ok. Or I can import a smaller lib, for example `import time` instead of `numpy`, and every thing is fine too.

By the way I'm using `Pycharm`, the **Max Heap Size** is set to 10,240 M.

Is there any way to solve this? Or I can only stuck with a smaller pool?

---

Update:

Perhaps this is an AMD CPU issue. I tried the same code on my laptop, which has a much weaker core i5 and 8G memory. No error at all.

Comment: Running a Process is a lot like launching a separate program with its own memory space.  For each process, the Python environment must import a separate copy of each imported module - therefore, you get 32 separate copies of the numpy library, complete with all of its DLLs.  That also applies to the Python interpreter and any other resource.  At some point you will run out of memory.  The only solution I know of is to refactor your program to import only what's really necessary, but I don't know of any good way to do that with a Process pool.

Comment: Yeah that's resonable. Maybe it's time to upgrade memory lol.